# Gaussian integers introduction

Tags: number-theory

[image: x]

on b),

Never seen this notation before so please correct any mistakes,

firstly I'm proving that if $N(S) = 1 \iff \exists v \in S$ s.t. $sv = 1$ right?

if so, here's my attempt,

1)

let$ s = a + b\sqrt{-2}$

$N(S) = 1 = a^2 + 2b^2 \implies \exists v$ s.t. sv = 1,

since $ N(S) = a^2 + 2b^2 = 1$ choose $v = a - b\sqrt{-2}$ so $sv = (a+b\sqrt{-2})(a-b\sqrt{-2}) = a^2 + 2b^2 = 1$ and we're done,

now prove $\exists v \in S$ s.t. $sv = 1 \implies N(S) = 1$

let $s = a + b \sqrt{-2}$ and $v = x + y\sqrt{-2}$ then $1 = (a+b\sqrt{-2})(x + y\sqrt{-2})$ so $N(1) = 1 = N(s)N(v) = (a^2 + 2b^2)(x^2 + 2y^2)$, now either $N(s) = 1$ and $N(v) = 1$ or $N(s) = -1$ and$ N(v) = -1$ seeing as everything is squared, all terms are non-negative so we get $N(s) = 1$

2)
next, proving $sv = 1 \iff s = 1,-1$ so $(a+b\sqrt{-2})(x+y\sqrt{-2}) = 1$ then s = 1 and v = 1 or s = -1 and v = -1 as we're dealing with integers (what else do I say here?)

proving the "only if" choose v = 1,-1 then $\exists v \in S $ s.t. $sv = 1$

could someone take a look at this and see what I can add in the second part

this for an algebra course which has some elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $sv = 1$, then $N(sv) = N(s)N(v) = 1$. But the norm is a non-negative integer so this forces $N(s) = N(v) = 1$.
- If $s = a+b\sqrt{-2}$ and $N(s) = 1$, then $a^2+2b^2 = 1$, and it is easy to see that this forces $(a,b) = (\pm 1, 0)$.

Comment: thanks for this, were there any other mistakes?

Comment: You are trying to prove that $s$ is a unit iff $s = \pm 1$. It's easier to show (as I have done here) that $N(s) = 1$ iff $s = \pm 1$. Those are equivalent statements, since you have already shown that $s$ is a unit iff $N(s) = 1$.

Comment: For 2) you have not really proved anything. $sv = 1$ implies $s=v=1$ or $s=v=-1$ is true in $\mathbf{Z}$, but here you want to prove that it is true in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. You can just write $s = q+b\sqrt{-2}$ and $v = c+d\sqrt{2}$ and expand, but it's easier (and more in the spirit of the topic) to reason on norms whenever possible.

Comment: after re-reading the question I believe I'm being asked to work with $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ but this changes nothing, thank you for your help